# Routing with AngularJS and MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been searching the web for solutions but cant't find any that will solve my problem.
I am trying to do client side routing with AngularJS and MVC.

This is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview) that I am using for guide lines but it does not help me. My MVS2 Project folder structure is as follows:
*$root/Views/Home/Home.html*

The error I get that the page could not be found. What am I missing here?

**AngularJS**

```
// create the module and name it myApp
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'Home.html',controller: 'mainController'})
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
// create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Home Page should appear here';
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
     </title>
</head
<body data-ng-controller="mainController">
    <div id="Div1">
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting Home.html from the browser just to be sure if it is really being served?

Comment: I have copied the url to my browser and does not find it. I am not sure how to structure my routing to get the correct page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC blocks the `Views` folder from being accessed! It will always return HTTP status 404!

**Why?** This is done for security. It prevents visitor from looking at your view files (ascx, cshtml, vbhtml, etc) which is source code.

**How it's done?** You will notice that `Views`folder has a `web.config`. `Web.config` is configured to return 404.

Here is a snippet of the `web.config`

```
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

Notice that for any path and any HTTP method, the handler is `HttpNotFoundHandler`

**Solution:** don't use the `View` folder for your AngularJS templates or modify `web.config` at your own risk

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information I did not know this at all. From your answer I decided to go a different route and it works perfectly. will post answer now

Answer (score 1):

The answer that LostInComputers gave me I have found a solution to inject html pages to my MVC project.

**.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/Home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/About.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

});
```

What I did was to create a *template* folder in my root directory and added my *.html* pages in there.
This works perfectly for me.